# How to Bind Values to form controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

I am trying to bind a value to ASP.NET form controls from an XML document. My end goal is to pre-populate form controls depending on the value the user selects in the ID dropdownlist. From there the user will be able to edit values and and save the changes back into the XML document.

My approach is trying to bind each xml id tag value to the dropdownlist. So far I have come up with this.

XML: registrations.xml

```
 <registrations>
      <Registration>
         <id>1</id>
         <fullName>Keiran Bernal</fullName>
         <emailAddress>k.bernal@gmail.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>Conference only</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>Yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>2</id>
         <fullName>Cordelia Pierce</fullName>
         <emailAddress>c.pierce@outlook.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>Conference and Dinner</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>Yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>3</id>
         <fullName>Zachery Guy</fullName>
         <emailAddress>z.guy@yahoo.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>Conference only</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>Yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>4</id>
         <fullName>Kiana Hawworth</fullName>
         <emailAddress>k.hawworth@bigpond.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>-</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>No</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
   </registrations>
```

Code Behind: edit.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet dsEdit = new DataSet();
        dsEdit.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/registrations.xml"));
        dllIdEdit.DataTextField = "fullName";
        dllIdEdit.DataValueField = "id";
        dllIdEdit.DataSource = dsEdit;
        dllIdEdit.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET Web Form: edit.aspx

```
 <%--ID--%>
 <asp:Label ID="lblIdEdit" runat="server" Text="ID" CssClass="editLbl"></asp:Label>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dllIdEdit" runat="server" CssClass="editDdl"></asp:DropDownList><br />
```

I got this from a few tutorials but for some reason the dropdownlist remains blank and can't figure out why.

Comment: Try binding to table 1 dllIdEdit.DataSource = dsEdit.Tables[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Page.IsPostBack

to !Page.IsPostBack
```

!Page.IsPostBack  essentially is the first time the page loads